# Can the election countdown be more precise?

Tags: feature-request, election

This has been bothering me for a while. The election countdown doesn't seem to care much for half hours. For example, as of posting of this question, there are one and a half hours till the election gets over. However, the countdown reads 1 hour.

Could this be made precise to at least half hours from next time onwards?

Comment: I read "election" and "fixed" in the title and was hoping for something way juicier than this...

Comment: @Yannis - too much politics.se?

Comment: Once it's less than an hour, it'll show minutes. You can always hover over to read the exact end time. This is how time/dates are throughout much of SE

Comment: @mhlester I know. But even hovering gives a UTC time. In other parts of SE, like when a post was edited or posted, the exact time isn't that necessary. But this is a little confusing, as I'm UTC +5:30, and running in the elections. That makes it a little awkward for me to figure out when the next phase starts from a glance

Comment: Looking at it a little differently, I kind of like it. Once the count down gets to minutes, the anxiety will kick in!

Comment: That is a good point about how it can be confusing for people that are in a +30 or +45 timezone.

Comment: @RaghavSood: Why is exact time more necessary here than at other places (e.g. when deciding if it's allowed to accept an answer or when checking if the bounty period is up)?

Comment: @RaghavSood, **status-completed** ;)